# ResNet 1x1 convolutions intuition

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, tensorflow2.0, resnet

Let's say I have a times series with accelerometer data with shape (None, 188, 1).

I am doing a classification task and challenged myself to implement the Resnet model.

```
def residual_block(inputs, filters, kernel_size, shortcut):

    out = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=filters, kernel_size=kernel_size,
                                 strides=1, padding='causal')(inputs)
    out = tf.keras.layers.ReLU()(out)
    out = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=filters, kernel_size=kernel_size,
                                 strides=1, padding='causal')(out)
    if shortcut:
        out = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(1, 1, padding="causal")(out)
    out = tf.keras.layers.add([inputs, out])
    out = tf.keras.layers.ReLU()(out)
    out = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool1D()(out)

    return out

def resnet_model(n_timesteps, n_features, n_classes):
    filters_1 = 16
    kernel_size_1 = 10

    filters_2 = 32
    kernel_size_2 = 10
    # head 1
    input1 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(n_timesteps, n_features))
    res_block1_1 = residual_block(input1, filters_1, kernel_size_1, shortcut=False)
    res_block1_2 = residual_block(res_block1_1, filters_2, kernel_size_2, shortcut=True)
    flatten1 = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(res_block1_2)

    dense1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu')(flatten1)
    drop1 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3)(dense1)
    dense2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu")(drop1)
    drop2 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3)(dense2)
    outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(n_classes, activation="softmax")(drop2)

    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input1, input2, input3],
                           outputs=outputs)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```

Initially I used only **one** residual block and everything was fine. It was when I added the second block that questions started to arise. If we go through the path of the data we can see that in the **first** block the `Add` layer receives the following shapes `(None, 188, 1)`(from the `input`) and `(None, 188, 16)`(from the `Convolution`) and the addition goes smoothly. Now for the second block I receive an error in the `Add` layer since it receives `(None, 94, 16)`(from the input which comes from the `MaxPooling`) and `(None, 94, 8)`(from the `Convolution`). So I added the **1x1 Convolution to fix this**, however I do not understand how the issue is fixed. It is stated that the **Resnet** needs the same shape as the input for the add so we use 1x1 convolutions, but `(None, 94, 1)`(after the 1x1 conv) and (None, 94, 16) are not the same shapes.

So my question is, how does the 1x1 convolution fix my issue? I understand what it does, just not how it combines with the `Add` layer.

Comment: This works because of broadcasting; the single feature map is stacked 16 times and then the shapes match. This is weird though, did you find this code somewhere else? You can just define the 1x1 convolution (`shortcut` with `n_filters`) as well. The 1x1 only refers to the kernel size.

Comment: Ah so the output of the 1x1 is just stacked to match the input of the block. That makes sense. I took inspiration for the shortcut from a few resources such as this: https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/data/9781838829131/2/ch02lvl1sec14/implementing-resnet-from-scratch. What do you mean when you say it's weird?

Comment: In the link you posted, they are also using `filters` many filters for the shortcut, i.e. the same number of filters as the output of the block. They do not use only a single filter as you are in your code. I meant that it's "weird" to only use a single filter as I've never seen this before.

Comment: Ahhh I see what you mean, in the 1x1 convolution layer I only put one filter. I thought I needed one filter because of the error message saying that the shapes were incompatible. I'll try adding the same number of filters. I wasn't sure since I'm working with 1d time series data and not 2d images.

Comment: I just tried it with filters instead of only 1 on the shortcut convolution and I got the same error message as before (still a kernel size of 1)

Comment: Oh I just found another big issue. You have to apply the shortcut to `inputs`, not to `out`. The whole point of the shortcut is to transform it such that you can add `inputs + out` (or rather `shortcut(inputs) + out` in that case) in case their shapes don't match.

Comment: Oh my, of course! That was a silly mistake from my end. Fixed it now. So my final question is since the input shape is (None, 188, 1) and on the first block, before the add we have (None, 188, 16) I should need the shortcut to correct the shape of the input correct? I don't understand why the Add layer does not complain about the shapes being incompatible